# Is it legal to clone a character from other game?

Tags: copyright, trademark

Is it legal to make a character very similar/exact from other game? E.g. take characters from Team Fortress 2 game, remake them in pixel art and use it in my game, but just change their names(with an intent to make money).

Would I get in trouble?

Comment: Such questions are usually better asked on https://law.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt there is no character related answer there

Answer (score 1):

When the IP holder whose characters you rip off feels like it, their lawyers can cause you all kinds of legal trouble. Copyright and IP lawsuits are civil lawsuits, and in civil lawsuits it's not about who is right, it's about who is right and has enough money to prove it.

Even if we assume the best case and a court ends up deciding that all their claims are ridiculous, this will be after you paid a fortune in legal fees and after various injunctions, subpoenas and DMCA takedown notices have already ruined your business.

Instead of ripping off someone else's IP, better develop your own. It's far safer and it's more fun anyway.